# Can I delete factory apps

Tags: applications, bloatware

What all apps that come factory on a LG 70 are safe to delete, or force stop, or disable without affecting the phones performance.

Answer (score 2):

Not all apps are safe to delete or disable. Most are, though.

- If you are able to remove an app that came with your phone, it is safe to do so.
- If you can only freeze the app, then it is in the `/system` directory, that is why you can not remove it. You can disable nearly any app without bad consequences - but if other apps start to crash, try to re-enable these apps.
- The apps you should never disable is the Settings app itself, the System UI and other core system components - without these, you may not be able to use the phone at all, so you can not even re-enable these. A factory reset can help this situation.

Answer (score 1):

Apps are safe to **Disable** when they provide an option of disabling them in app manager. They won't affect the performance of the device (and disabling some apps may increase battery back-up). For example apps from Google like Newsstand and Books, Google Music, Play Games, Google+ etc are all safe to disable. Also apps from LG like Live Wallpapers are also safe to disable. So you can disable almost all the apps with no effect on device.

*Note: You won't find **Disable** button beside app in app manager if it is not safe to disable it. Here Disable can be replaced by uninstall, delete. Force stop must be used carefully sometimes.*